# Images missing, service unavailable

Tags: image

Folks:

When users visit the site only some of the images on the page show. Checking Chrome dev tools shows that the missing images are failing with "server unavailable" errors. The image is there if you go to it directly.

This appears to be random. Images show sometimes but not others. I have erased the cache, rebuilt the search index and the asset list. No change.

The client says that the site sometime fails completely but I have yet to witness this.

I have VPNed from various locations and it seems to be the same no matter where I'm coming from.

The hosting company says the only error they see is "image missing" and the DB connection is fine.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> The hosting company says the only error they see is "image missing" and the DB connection is fine.

That seems suspicious to me.  Assuming the 503 Service Unavailable status code is initiated in Craft, it will do that in two common occurrences for front-end requests.  One is when Craft is in the middle of being updated, and the other is when it is having problems connecting to the database.

A look through the Craft logs as well as your web server access logs should help verify this.

Comment: Thanks for this. The 503 is not served up by Craft. All you see is a broken image on the front end and the service unavailable for that image in Chrome dev tools. I'm guessing that this is just the server dropping the ball and taking too long to respond with the image. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Mystery finally solved. An SEO company was running some tests against the site that day and basically hammered the server too hard. Why they were testing against a live site is beyond me.